# String comparison and unicode

Tags: qt, qstring, qsort, qlist, qtcore

I'm using `qSort` in Qt to sort `QList` containing struct. I noticed that Polish character "Ś" is at the end or beginning of sorted list (depending on order). Is there any string comparison function which places "Ś" next to "S"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `QString::localeAwareCompare` for your comparison function.