# compare a character with an unicode in Qt

Tags: c++, string, qt, c++11

```
if (lineEditText[i] == 'đ' || lineEditText[i] == 'Đ')
     lineEditText.replace(i, 1, "d");
```

i want to compare character at (i) type QString with an unicode as above. But it does not work. So how can i compare it?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19433805/string-comparison-and-unicode) may help (and be a duplicate).

Comment: This is likely related to character encoding issues - what source encoding does your compiler expect, and what encoding is the source file in?  It should Just Work in a ISO-8859-1 or UTF-16 environment, but may be problematic if `đ` and `Đ` are multibyte characters (e.g. in UTF-8 or ISO-2022-JP).  It's worth making sure that your compiler warns about multibyte literals - you can test it with a simple `'xx'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build `QString`s out of characters and use them for comparison:

```
if (lineEditText[i] == QString("đ")[0] || lineEditText[i] == QString("Đ")[0])
```

or use [wide character literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal) so they got correctly cast to `QChar`:

```
if (lineEditText[i] == L'đ' || lineEditText[i] == L'Đ')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the unicode character from its hex code and passing it to `QChar(uint(hexValue)`. As long as the data types on both sides are the same, you can compare with a '==' for a QChar.

```
uint unicodeCapitalD = 0x00D0
unit unicodeSmallD = 0x0111
if (lineEditText[i] == QChar(unicodeSmallD) || lineEditText[i] == QChar(unicodeCapitalD))
    //whatever you want to do
```

Edit: My previous answer was focused on generating a [QString containing the unicode character](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#fromUcs4) instead of a `QChar`. `QString::fromUcs4()` did not work because you were trying to compare it with specific character in the QLineEdit against the unicode character (I should've generated a QChar instead of a QString for the comparison).

Comment: i have tried it but i see an error: no macth for operato == (types are QCharRef and QString)

Comment: I think Aditya meant `QChar(unicodeCapitalD)` and  `QChar(unicodeSmallD)`, rather than creating `QString` objects.  (or even `static const QChar unicodeCapitalD(0x00D0);` and then simply `lineEditText[i] == unicodeCapitalD`, etc)

Comment: Toby is right. Changed my answer to reflect this. I overlooked that you were trying to compare.